# Was Paula going to fire Kate?

Tags: plot-explanation, no-reservations

In the 2007 film *No Reservations*, when Paula offers Nick a permanent position at the restaurant was she planning on firing Kate, or would Nick and Kate both be head chefs, sharing the kitchen?

Nick says he'd accept the offer, but wants to check with Kate first, and later tells Kate that Paula offered him the job, but he declined.

He'd never consider the offer if it meant Kate would lose her job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Paula was going to fire Kate if Nick took her job.

Nick is originally offered a job as a sou-chef to fill in when Kate is grieving the death of her sister.

The night that Kate calls in to spend the day with Zoe, Nick and Paula talk and Paula offers Nick a permanent position.

> **Paula** You've really mastered the menu, Nick. You put your signature on the dishes, and all the regulars have noticed. How would you like to stay on permanently?
>
> **Nick** I think I'd like that.
>
> [Source](http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/n/no-reservations-script-transcript.html)

Yes, Paula was planning on firing Kate if Nick excepted her offer.  Kate begins to notice Paula paying more attention to Nick and asking him to do more things and confronts him.  Nick then admits to Kate that he was offered her job.

> **Nick** "She offered me your job."
>
> **Kate** "What?
>
> **Kate** "Why didn't you tell me?"

Paula clearly shows a lot of distaste in Kate throughout the film, especially with her short fuse for customers. This is shown in the beginning when Kate confronts one who complains and once again toward the end when Kate slams a raw steak down on a customer's table. Paula also forced Kate to see a therapist or she was going to be fired.  So it is no surprise that Paula offered Nick her job.

Comment: This is what I assumed. I guess I was thrown off by Nick's eagerness to accept the offer. He had clearly developed feelings for Kate at this point in the film, and if he took the offer she'd have lost her job. His whole "I think I'd like that." comment just kinda threw me. It just didn't seem to fit, coming from a guy who is supposed to have feelings for Kate. So, I had to be sure if Paula was planning on canning Kate or having two executive chefs. Thanks. :)